# Multilingual setup with different content structure per language

Tags: matrix, localization

We'd like to setup a multilingual site with a parallel structure but different content per language. The content will differ specifically in the matrix fields that there will be. For example, German "About us" might have "Image, Text, Image, Text, Text" and French would have "Text, Text". Currently any setup I tried deletes matrix fields from German if I delete them from French. Is there anyway to get out of this? I haven't found a relevant setting so far, but I may well be missing something. Thanks a lot for info.

Comment: Welcome to the Craft CMS Stack Exchange, @Jane! It doesn’t sound like your Matrix field [is translatable](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/sites.html#step-3-define-your-translatable-fields)—can you check whether it is? (May need to check the field’s Propagation Method setting.)